# Acceleration in Twin's paradox

Tags: special-relativity

The Twin's paradox is a well known paradox in which there is a difference in the ages of twins after one twin travels a round trip around the space and returns back while the other twin stays put. I understood how the gap in their ages arises because of the finite acceleration time taken during the change of velocity while the travelling twin takes a turn. But my question is, when he starts decelerating/ accelerating, won't he observe the other twin decelerating/ accelerating too? I mean, if I'm accelerating away from a reference position, that point will also accelerate in the opposite direction in my frame, right? I searched the internet for relevant answers to this question to which I didn't find anything concrete. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The central thing you're missing here is that **you can tell when you're in an accelerating frame**.

If one twin notices that objects that aren't tied down begin to accelerate without being acted upon by any forces, then he knows that he is in a non-inertial frame, and that his observation that the other twin is accelerating is due to *his own* acceleration.

Comment: The "without being acted upon by any forces" is an interesting reservation. If you feel a force, you may not know if you're being accelerated or feeling the force of gravity of some external object - to you, both feel exactly the same. This is why general relativity predicts time dilation is caused by gravity as well - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation. It is curious we don't think that other 1/r^2 forces (e.g., EM force) cause time dilation - but I don't know why, or whether this was actually tested.

Comment: What if the amount of acceleration is so very small as to not be detected by you? Then how would you know?

Comment: @BradS  There is no need for your brain to know... "nature" knows (ofc the effect continiously gets smaller and smaller).