Not "understanding" the Twin Paradox?
Many of the explanations that I've seen of the Twin Paradox seem to rely on the role of acceleration to explain the differences between the twins. But why can't we simply resolve it just via "length contraction" alone?
If twin A stays on Earth while twin B flies off to some planet located $d$ meters away (that is, $d$ meters away in Earth's frame where both planets are rest) at some relativistic speed $v \approx c$, don't we then already have the requisite "asymmetry" in terms of what both twins see anyway?
Twin A will see Twin B flying away at $v$ a distance of $d$ meters for $d/v$ seconds, while Twin B will see Twin A flying away at $v$ for a distance of $d/\gamma$ for $t/\gamma$ seconds (because length contraction shortens the road length for twin B). Hence, both twins will already "not see the other take the same path" so we would already have an asymmetry from the get-go and therefore the claim in the paradox that "both twins see the same thing" already goes into the trash can.
Since pretty much all the explanations rely on twin B's "acceleration" to explain the paradox, what am I missing here? It seems way too simple to merely say "length contraction = no twin paradox" (even though neither twin will agree on the trip distance anyway) without having to invoke any fancy acceleration and/or change in reference frames, so I'm pretty sure there's something I'm missing here.
**Edit:
In other words -- with time dilation & length contraction in SR, it easily "already" makes sense that different observers can observe time and distance differently. For example, let's say I'm timing my friend who is sprinting on a 100m track from some start to finish line, while both of us are holding a stopwatch and ruler in each hand. His procedure is:

Accelerate instantly to $v \approx c$ from the start line
Then instantly start the stopwatch
Run at constant $v$ from start to finish line
Stop the stopwatch
Decelerate instantly back to rest in my frame

So, from my point of view, he just ran at a speed of $v$ for 100m in 100m/v seconds. But according to him, he also ran at a speed of $v$ (relative to the start/mid/finish line), but instead for $d/\gamma$ meters and $d/(\gamma v)$ seconds from his point of view (he is carrying his own ruler and own stopwatch). So, while we both agree on our relative $v$, we do not agree on the exact distance traveled and the exact duration (only their ratio, i.e v = distance/time). And this makes sense -- speed is a ratio of distance/time, and so just because we agree upon that ratio does not imply that we "also" have to agree on exactly what numerator (distance) and denominator (time) were used.
So, what am I missing here? If we accept that SR allows different observers to measure distances and times differently, there seems to be no contradiction here nor any possible "twin paradox" to speak of. In other words (even if the runner makes a second lap back to the start line again), what is described by the "twin paradox" would actually be my expectation instead, rather than some odd/unexpected result!

"Virtually all of the explanations of the Twin Paradox seem to rely on the role of acceleration to explain the differences between the twins." --- citation needed.

@WillO Good point -- I've updated that to "Many explanations that I've seen..."! Here's are some links: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/how-is-the-classical-twin-paradox-resolved#comment7138_2554, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2560/168695, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503069/acceleration-in-twins-paradox I'll post some more links soon too

Re, "...acceleration...," I don't feel qualified to explain it myself, but "they" say (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox#Relativity_of_simultaneity) that you don't need to talk about the acceleration per se. What's important apparently is that the Earthbound twin's point of view can be explained within a single frame of reference, but to describe the travelling twin's experience requires two different frames of reference; one for the outbound part of the journey, and one for the homeward bound part.

@SolomonSlow Yes -- the change of reference frame, caused by acceleration, can explain the missing time gap. My "misinterpretation" here was assuming the twin paradox was merely about each twin's own proper times merely being different, rather than a more extensive accounting for the perceived "time gap" between their measurements for one another as explained in Jeb's answer.

So in your set up, the inbound and outbound legs of the trip look the same. If I write (per leg):
$$ \tau^A_A = \frac D v $$
for the proper time that $A$ sees $A$ experience, and
$$ \tau_B^A = \tau^A_A / \gamma =\frac 1 {\gamma} \frac D v$$
for the proper time that $A$ sees $B$ experience, then we have:
$$ \tau_B^B = \tau_B^A $$
for the proper time $B$ sees $B$ experience.
No paradox.
The problem appears when we consider $B$ looking at $A$'s proper time, which is dilated relative to $B$'s clock:
$$ \tau_A^B = \tau_B^B/\gamma = \frac 1 {\gamma^2} \frac D v$$
So when we add both legs:
$A$ sees $A$ tick off:
$$ T_A^A = 2\frac D v$$
and $B$ ticks for:
$$ T_B^A = \frac 2 {\gamma}\frac D v = T_B^B $$
in both frames, but $B$ see $A$'s clock only tick off:
$$ T_A^B = \frac 2 {\gamma^2}\frac D v$$
and at the end, $A$ and $B$ share world-lines again so $B$ has missing time:
$$ T_A^A-T_A^B = \frac{2D}v(1 - \frac 1 {\gamma^2}) 
=\frac{2Dv}{c^2}
$$
Where did it go?

I see -- so the Twin Paradox is actually much more specifically about accounting for the "missing time" (rather than merely just stating each twins' "proper time" is different from the other). In which case, the role of acceleration + change in reference frames is now a lot more clear and important!

Thank you for the clarification!! As the mathematical analysis (and spacetime diagrams) accounting for this discrepancy are posted in many other questions/answers here (and also here, under "Too Many Analyses: a Meta Objection" as well), there probably no need to repeat them here. Will go ahead and mark your answer as accepted then!

@ManRow the takeaway is the "missing time" happens when space twin turns around, which makes the time on Earth jump forward (or backward if he turns around again)...it's not time-dilation, rather it is a change in the clock bias (when is now?, what is simultaneous?) back on earth, outside the light cone.  Now, it is mathematically equivalent to gravitational time dilation in a uniform apparent field caused by $+v \rightarrow -v$, but I don't think that's a good starting point for the paradox. The paradox is that the time on Earth depends on the direction space twin moves (Andromeda Paradox).
